# server filter kendoui scheduler and refresh

Tags: json, kendo-ui, scheduler, kendo-scheduler

It's possible set a filter based on start date and end date on kendoui scheduler?

My problem is that I have about 25000 records to extract and it's impossible send all this data in json.

So I want filter my server request. and refresh data every click on change date.

thanks.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?  I am having this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and resolve with this example:
http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/web/scheduler/kendoui-scheduler-server-filtering.aspx

I hope this help you.

Comment: Sorry, but I use Php. I'll try to see on a .net machine. Thx Miguel!

Comment: Miguel your code is ok! just copied your parameter map and setserverfiltering to true! thanks again