# Kendo Scheduler: filter remote data by start and end dates

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I've got the Kendo Scheduler widget displaying events from a remote datasource. It's working fine, but I can't find a way to filter the remote data by the appropriate `start` and `end` dates, so only the data required for the current view is retrieved.

There's a partial solution here: [server filter kendoui scheduler and refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883406/server-filter-kendoui-scheduler-and-refresh) but I'm looking for the ability to utilise the standard datasource filters (which my PHP server-side script is already configured to handle).

Any ideas?

Edit: I've found a workaround, but it's not perfect as it causes two datasource reads, but it works:

```
navigate: function(e) {
    $('#scheduler').data("kendoScheduler").dataSource.filter([{ field: 'start', operator: 'gte', value: moment(e.date).subtract('months',1).format('YYYY-MM-DD') },{ field: 'end', operator: 'lte', value: moment(e.date).add('months',1).format('YYYY-MM-DD') }]);
}
```

This is using the moment.js date library to handle date functions, but that's obviously optional.

Also, it may be best to ask a separate question for this, but... I have a problem when using an eventTemplate. I can no longer resize events - just drag/move them (though the resize handles are displayed).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having similar use case.